# How to map 3 different objects on a table

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to map 3 different objects that I get when I make a call to an API.

The goal is to print async, one at a time so the page does not take many time to load.

There's just one call that gets these objects, it's a call to a dynamic URL, so I change the parameters on a loop and I get the response.

The objects come like this:

Object 1

```
{
  Name: one
  Group: one
}
```

Object 2

```
{
  Name: two
  Group: two
}
```

Object 3

```
{
  Name: three
  Group: three
}
```

What I was trying to achieve was mapping these objects one per line, like a table:

```
Name: one     Group: one
Name: two     Group: two
Name: three   Group: three
```

Instead, I get them on the same line. The object changes from the first one to the last. The last stays, as if iterating through all of them and stopping at the last one.

My call to the API:

```js
export default function Machines({data}) {

     const classes = useStyles()
     const style = styles();

     const name_Machines = data.map((row)=>{
         return (row.name);
     });

     const resource_group = data.map((row)=>{
         return (row.resource_group);
     });

    let url
    const [MachinesRow, setMachinesRow] = React.useState([])
    React.useEffect(() => {
    resource_group.forEach((keyword, index) => {
     url = "/api/machine/" + keyword + "/" + name_Machines[index]
     fetch(url, {
       method: "GET",
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         Authorization: "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
       },
     })
        .then(resp => {
        return resp.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
        setMachinesRow([...MachinesRow, ...[data]])
        })
        .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
        window.location.replace("/")
        })
     })
    }, [])
```

My code:

```js
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>Azure machines</h1>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">resource_group</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">location</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">status</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {MachinesRow.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
              <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
                <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
                     <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
                  </StyledButton>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.location}</TableCell>
               <TableCell  key= {row.name + row.resource_group}align="left">
                 <MachineStatusIcon
                  status_code={row.status_code}
                  status={row.status}
            />
               </TableCell>

          </TableRow>
         ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set your callback functions to call:

```
setMachinesRow([...MachinesRow, ...[data]])
```

you are creating a new Array object while using the original MachinesRow which is an empty Array object (You create all 3 callbacks from the same scope). Doing it 3 times will leave you with the last data set, because each one will replace the previous with empty data + the request result.

**Edit**

Do this instead.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const resultsPromise = resource_group.map((keyword, index) => {
        url = "/api/machine/" + keyword + "/" + name_Machines[index]
        return fetch(url, {...})
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
                window.location.replace("/")
            })
    })

    Promise.all(resultsPromise).then(results => setMachinesRow([...MachinesRow, ...results]));
}, [])
```

You might need to work the data on *results*, this is just an example of how to set you in a position where you have all your data in one place

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I' am new to react and this for me is quite advanced, what's the way to fix it? to get all api calls and print them on a table.

Comment: @PatrickJosé Asking him to give you fish while he is trying to teach you how to fishing =).

Comment: @ilkerkaran If i understood what he said, i would do it, them problem here is that i am very green in this language, and what i can make it's by looking from other examples, and simple things :)

Comment: @Gabriel but in that way the call will be all in the same array no? And what i am trying to achieve is an async call, one at time so the page loads faster

Comment: You'll be doing 3 calls at the same time. Notice I changed foreach to map. That will return you 3 promises which will be awaited on with Promise.All.

Comment: @GabrielFerrarini thanks, there is some Unexpected token error, that I'am trying to figure it out, it points to the `return fetch(url, {...})` on the {}

Comment: @PatrickJosé, you should have used your own object for the second parameter of fetch, he wrote that to shorten the code

Comment: @ilkerkaran thanks, didn't notice that, newb here :)

Comment: @PatrickJosé, No worries, we all have been there. Happy Coding!